# To view PDF in android generated in Crystal Report

Tags: android

I have a PDF file which is generated in crystal Report  version 13.0.0.99 which
generate a Pdf of Version  1.7 .but all other PDF which is not generated by Crystal Report can read in my application.
this link will get PDF file I created using Crystal Report.

http://www.mediafire.com/?d9b444vx0102vea

when i view this pdf in android i got the out put as

http://www.mediafire.com/view/?v0wzlqzhzqtiswb

what  should I do to see this pdf  in my application itself ?

Comment: what you want to do with PDF file ?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of sources for opening/ editing pdf(not sure from your question) on stackoverflow

> 1.) Use an intent to open a pdf - it ll open using an existing pdf viewer installed
>
> 2.) Take a look at
>
> [PDF Library for Android - PDFBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952626/pdf-library-for-android-pdfbox/5953194#5953194)
>
> [Android PDF Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087454/android-pdf-rendering)

for open source libraries, commercial ones etc.,
Basically pdf and android dont go well together from a developer standpoint